# java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a simple thread that goes like this:

```
public class AwesomeRunnable extends Thread {

    Handler thisHandler = null;
    Handler uihandler = null;
    String update = null;
    long time = 0;

    public AwesomeRunnable(Handler h, long howLong) {
        uihandler = h;
        time = howLong;
    }

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        thisHandler = new Handler();
  ...
```

**EDIT: ADDED CODE THAT STARTS THE RUNNABLE**

```
public class StartCycle implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        pomodoroLeft = numPomodoro;
        while(pomodoroLeft > 0) {
            pomodoroLeft--;
            actualSeconds = 6 * ONE_SECOND;
            runnable = new AwesomeRunnable(myHandler, actualSeconds);
            runnable.start();
            waitForClock();
```

It is an inner class of a main activity. **This thread**, however runs **not on the main** activity, but inside of **another thread that runs** on the **main** activity.

Anyway, this example is *exactly* the same as [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quit%28%29), but for some reason it gives me java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread.

I did not create any other loopers, at least explicitly anywhere.

Comment: Can you show the code that starts the `AwesomeRunnable`?

Comment: That looks fine.  Which line is throwing the exception?  Which thread?  (If you're looking at the logcat output in a terminal window, use `adb logcat -v threadtime` to show the thread ID on each line.)  Something must be creating a looper twice in a single thread, so you need to figure out if it's running in the wrong thread, or something running twice in the new thread.

Comment: @fadden `Looper.prepare();` is throwing the exception. Ok...will try to go through log output as you suggested.

Comment: @fadden Actually the first line of the error message is: FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Does it mean it somehow creates another looper on the main thread? But why?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to.  If the two numbers (pid and tid) are the same, then it's definitely trying to create a new Looper in the main thread.  Check the stack trace and see what's calling the function.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread

The exception is thrown because you (or core Android code) has already called `Looper.prepare()` for the current executing thread.

The following checks whether a Looper already exists for the current thread, if not, it creates one, thereby avoiding the `RuntimeException`.

```
    public void run() 
    {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            {
              Looper.prepare();
            }
            thisHandler = new Handler();

         ....
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provided some sort of explanation along with your code.

Comment: simple and straightforward, worked for me too, thank you so much

Comment: in Android not work into -> adapter  Recycle - > ViewHolder  - >view.setOnClickListener

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: `myLooper` the naming is really funny.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of just calling `Looper.prepare();`, first check if `Looper` does not already exist for your `Thread`, if not, call that function. Like this:

```
if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
    Looper.prepare();
```