# Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: android, looper, android-looper

With the following code:

```
private void showDialog(String message) {
    try
    {
    Looper.prepare();
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), notification);
                r.play();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                UserPrefs.setLogerForException(Log.getStackTraceString(e).toString(),
                        GlobalContext.Myglobalcontext,ApiConstants.Excption_Log_Message);
            }
            CustomAlert alertDialog = new CustomAlert();
            alertDialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_tite));
            alertDialog.setMessage(msg.obj.toString());
            alertDialog.setAlertId(Events.MORE_INFO);
            alertDialog.setTextGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            ReplicaPrefs.showAlert(alertDialog);
        }
    };

    Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
    msgObj.obj = message    ;
    handler.handleMessage(msgObj);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        UserPrefs.setLogerForException(Log.getStackTraceString(ex).toString(),
                GlobalContext.Myglobalcontext,ApiConstants.Excption_Log_Message);
    }

}
```

After some time (not the exact scenario) I have the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread at android.os.Looper.prepare

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look on this to understand about the lopper: [What is the purpose of Looper and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it)

Then, take a look on this: [java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038682/java-lang-runtimeexception-only-one-looper-may-be-created-per-thread) for finding the answer for your question.

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

Take note: Every `Handler` is bundle with one `Looper`, which only one `Looper` may be created per thread.  So, you can create an `Handler` instance by constructor of `Handler(Looper)`. When using `Handler()` to create one instance, the default `Looper` is from the **Main UI Thread** on which current `Activity`s run.

As for your codes above, you defined `showDialog(String message)` in an `Activity`, right? So, that means this method will be called on the **Main UI Thread**. Consequently, when you create a `Handler` instance by constructor of `Handler()` inside `showDialog(String message)`, the `Looper` from the **Main UI Thread** will be bundled with the `Handler` instance by default. That means `Looper.prepare();` is redundant and then removing `Looper.prepare();` will solve your problem.

Comment: Not exactly.  `Handler()` uses the current thread and throws an exception if the current thread is not a `Looper`.  That's normally, but not necessarily the main thread.

Comment: Yes, `Handler()` will bundled with the `Looper` created by the `Thread` on which `showDialog(String message)` run. In this case, `showDialog(String message)` run on the **Main UI Thread**.